# I tried to install Microsoft Office with wine on Ubuntu 20.04 but it keeps saying it encountered a problem

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I tried to install Microsoft Office on Linux with wine but it kept saying it encountered a program.

Comment: please add the exact error message and info like version of wine and MS office

Comment: Installing Windows in VBox miht be an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly at a tangent - what does microsoft office have that is not available in LibreOffice (file compatible) that is part of the base Ubuntu install.
I appreciate there are some niche features that need MSO but have you tried LibreOffice - it reads and writes the files well.

Wine may need 32 bit libraries available to run some software - many posts on this on here

Installing from a terminal / command line may give more information on the "problem" which will allow a solution for you.